# Git errors in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have been using git in VS 2019 CE for 2yrs without any problems. I have just installed VS 2022 and git doesn't seem to work. In VS 2022 CE I loaded a uncontrolled solutions then used git to initialise and push the loaded solution. It appears to have created the repository but not pushed the files. It reports there have been errors but doesn't tell me what the errors are. The snapshot below shows the screen - nothing seems to change from first loading a newly installed VS 2022 until after clicking the 'Create Git Repository button'. Clicking 'Add to source Control' or 'Select repository' doesn't seems to change the state of the screen. I have reloaded VS and re-booted & reloaded VS without success.  I have tried the solutions suggested in SO without success. one solution suggested typing 'git status' into the Package Manager Console - the PMC said git was not a known command.
[image: Screen shot of git in VS.]

Do I have to load an extension to get it working?

Comment: This just happened to me after I updated VS 2022 from 17.1.3 to 17.1.5. The error message I see from the Output panel is "One or more errors occurred." The local repo can be opened in git GUI just fine. No idea what this means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git has stopped working after installing VS 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891061/git-has-stopped-working-after-installing-vs-2022)

Answer (score 1):

"git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Projects/repo1"

Not sure if same issue, but to me looks like i had the same issue with the git repo not being recognised inside Visual studio.

For me, after clearing VS cache and Clearing Temp files of user and updating git, what fixed the issue was: "git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Projects/repo1". No idea why it would be required though.

Answer (score 1):

Open VS as an administrator.  Once I did that it worked.

Note, I wasn't able to change the owner to myself because it couldn't see my network identity.  Since the owner was administrator I decided to try opening VS as administrator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to have been fixed in the latest release, but I am still experiencing a similar issue (cannot create Git Repository).

My workaround for this is to create the repository in VS 2019. Once the repository is created, everything worked in VS2022. I have to do this for every new project though.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the common solution, but it worked for me.  Note I typically use Start Menu shortcuts to solution files (.sln) to open VS solutions, which eventually runs devenv.exe.

When it came time for my most recent commit, I found that when I went to the git window in VS2022 17.7.1, the local repo I had been working with had vanished, and clicking the Create Git Repository or Add to Source Control buttons didn’t do anything.  Researching after the panic subsided, I found some folks set deveve.exe to run as admin.  I tried opening VS as admin, then opening the solution, and the git window looked like it should, repo was there.  Then I opened VS normally, and then the solution, and the git window looked like it should. However, opening the solution by clicking on the solution file still resulted in an empty git window.

What happened was that couple days ago when editing xaml, I chose the View | Design in Blend menu, which apparently downloaded and installed Blend.  I haven’t worked with it since, just wanted to see what it looked like.  However, I noticed that all my solution files now had a Blend icon, though Visual Studio opened when they were clicked.

The fix was to open the property dialog for one of the .sln files, and on the General tab, I saw the Opens With item was set to Blend for Visual Studio 2022, with a Change button to its right.  I changed the Opens With value to Microsoft Visual Studio, and now my repos appear properly in the git window.  Also, changing just one .sln file changed the association for all of them, so there was not need to fuss with all of them.