# LibGit2Sharp Exception: repository path not owned by current user

Tags: c#, .net-core, libgit2sharp

I have a Windows server application that runs as a system user (non-interactive, no home directory etc) that accesses a git repository using libgit2sharp. Code that was working with v0.26.2 breaks in v.0.27.0 & later.

The application breaks when creating a Repository object at this point:

using (Repository repo = new Repository(pathToRepo));

with exception:

LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: repository path '[path]' is not owned by current user

Code works fine prior to v.027.0.

The process definitely has full access to the repository location (e.g. can write files).

I've seen various references to this error in relation to libgit, the suggested fix for which is to add a git config setting like this:

[safe]
directory = *

I've manually added this to the repository config file (.git\config) but the exception still occurs.

Am I missing something or is this a bug? Should I be adding the setting somewhere else, and if so, where (given this is a system user with no $HOME directory)?

Comment: So a bug was fixed in from previous version the allowed unauthorized people from accessing the file.  Only the user or an admin can read/write the file.  May be running as admin will work.  VS does run in Admin unless you right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin or run the exe output from c#.

Comment: Thanks, but comment doesn't really address the question.

Comment: You do not have the permission to write the file.  You need to change permission or run as admin.

Comment: The process does have permission to write to the repo directory, as I said in the original post. That isn't the problem. The problem is that the suggested fix using the safe directory setting doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Look at path settings at following : https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp?force_isolation=true#optimizing-unit-testing

Comment: I don't see how that helps, please explain?

Comment: Answering my own question here, but on further research & testing I can get the [safe] directory = * setting recognised by adding it to the C:\Program Files\git\etc\gitconfig file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT Repository appears to be owned by another user on your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890948/git-repository-appears-to-be-owned-by-another-user-on-your-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but on further research & testing I can get the

[safe]
directory = *

setting recognised only by adding it to either:
C:\Program Files\git\etc\gitconfig file (if git is installed)
or
C:\ProgramData\Git\config (if git is not installed)